Unable to boot qemu/libvirt Windows 11 from physical disk partition - error 0xc0000001
My end goal is to have the same physical partition on disk booted either as a primary OS (the way you boot into Windows day in day out, just to be clear...) AND reuse the very same partition to boot a VM within qemu/libvirt.
In order to do so, I have created a 'virtual disk' with device mapper.
Virtual disk is there to:

provide a different EFI partition (through loop device and a file on file system) - this is needed so that Windows thinks it is alone on the PC (well.. technically... it is needed to avoid grub picking up within my VM)
and to mask the Linux partition (Which I have already mounted read-write... so probably a good idea to avoid it mounted twice, no?)

From there, I create a VM in libvirt, with pass-through TPM. Pass-through seems to work as expected - i.e. I am able to boot from either physical of virtual and I can log in with PIN.
I found out during my tests that I should definitely disable Fast Boot within Windows (which basically is hibernation?) - so that's done
Now, the issue:

I am able to boot from physical using this disk
I am able to boot from a VM defined in VirtualBox with this disk
I WAS initially able to boot into libvirt (virt-manager). BUT after applying all updates, not any more...
I also extracted the command line (ps -fe and a lot of vi) and to run directly qemu from command line  - but get the very same issue.

I think I have exhausted all causes I can think of.

I have recreated many times the BCD in Windows (remember: I have different EFI partitions...) - considering maybe a change in disk technology...
I have tried to 'repair' my windows (from install media)
I have applied the updates from the virtual machine - and very bad things have happened (VM unable to boot afterwards - but Physical machine OK)
I have applied the updates from the physical boot - and as you would expect; updates work and system is perfectly working afterwards EXCEPT it won't boot any more as VM...
I THINK that I noticed that if I apply big changes within the VM (like coupling Windows with my OneDrive - which would then sync all files) the system won't boot afterwards.
If I manage to boot into Safe Mode, my System sees the C: partition and seems happy with it (no errors whatsoever...)
I have run the sfc /scannow (no errors) and BOOTREC /SCANOS; BOOTREC /FIXMBR; BOOTREC /FIXBOOT; BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD. But no luck (I mean they run fine, but the system still refuse to start).

I'm out of options.
Plus, there is this thing which puzzles me: the very same (virtual) disk would work from a VM on VirtualBox
Any hint on where to look / what to change on my VM definition / why it fails?
(anything... I'm close to being desperate at this point)
For reference: here is the libvirt xml definition:
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>winvirt</name>
  <uuid>42ee3d0e-2ccd-4427-9bc4-565b277c30b9</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/11"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os firmware='efi'>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-8.2'>hvm</type>
    <firmware>
      <feature enabled='yes' name='enrolled-keys'/>
      <feature enabled='yes' name='secure-boot'/>
    </firmware>
    <loader readonly='yes' secure='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd</loader>
    <nvram template='/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd'>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/winvirt_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv mode='custom'>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
    <smm state='on'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none' migratable='on'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/data/isos/Win11_23H2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/data/isos/virtio-win-0.1.262.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdc' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/mapper/lbd'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <shareable/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0x17'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0x18'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='10' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='10' port='0x19'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='11' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='11' port='0x1a'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='12' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='12' port='0x1b'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='13' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='13' port='0x1c'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='14' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='14' port='0x1d'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='15' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='15' port='0x1e'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='16' model='pcie-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pcie-pci-bridge'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:bf:ec:a4'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='e1000e'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <tpm model='tpm-tis'>
      <backend type='passthrough'>
        <device path='/dev/tpm0'/>
      </backend>
    </tpm>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich9'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1b' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <audio id='1' type='spice'/>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <watchdog model='itco' action='reset'/>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>

And the bash script I have created out of it:
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -name guest=win11,debug-threads=on \
    -blockdev node-name=flash0-storage,driver=file,filename=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd,auto-read-only=true,discard=unmap \
    -blockdev node-name=flash0-format,driver=raw,file=flash0-storage,read-only=true \
    -blockdev node-name=flash1-storage,driver=file,filename=/home/precchia/winvirt_VARS.fd,auto-read-only=true,discard=unmap \
    -blockdev node-name=flash1-format,read-only=false,driver=raw,file=flash1-storage \
    -blockdev node-name=libvirt-2-storage,driver=host_device,filename=/dev/mapper/lbd,auto-read-only=true,discard=unmap \
    -blockdev node-name=libvirt-2-format,read-only=false,driver=raw,file=libvirt-2-storage \
    -blockdev node-name=libvirt-1-storage,driver=file,filename=/data/isos/Win11_23H2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso,auto-read-only=true,discard=unmap \
    -blockdev node-name=libvirt-1-format,read-only=true,driver=raw,file=libvirt-1-storage \
    -machine pc-q35-8.2,usb=off,vmport=off,smm=on,dump-guest-core=off,memory-backend=pc.ram,pflash0=flash0-format,pflash1=flash1-format,hpet=off,acpi=on \
    -device id=pci.1,driver=pcie-root-port,port=16,chassis=1,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=true,addr=0x2 \
    -device id=pci.2,driver=pcie-root-port,port=17,chassis=2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x1 \
    -device id=pci.3,driver=pcie-root-port,port=18,chassis=3,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x2 \
    -device id=pci.4,driver=pcie-root-port,port=19,chassis=4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x3 \
    -device id=pci.5,driver=pcie-root-port,port=20,chassis=5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4 \
    -device id=pci.6,driver=pcie-root-port,port=21,chassis=6,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x5 \
    -device id=pci.7,driver=pcie-root-port,port=22,chassis=7,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x6 \
    -device id=pci.8,driver=pcie-root-port,port=23,chassis=8,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x7 \
    -device id=pci.9,driver=pcie-root-port,port=24,chassis=9,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=true,addr=0x3 \
    -device id=pci.10,driver=pcie-root-port,port=25,chassis=10,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x1 \
    -device id=pci.11,driver=pcie-root-port,port=26,chassis=11,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x2 \
    -device id=pci.12,driver=pcie-root-port,port=27,chassis=12,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x3 \
    -device id=pci.13,driver=pcie-root-port,port=28,chassis=13,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x4 \
    -device id=pci.14,driver=pcie-root-port,port=29,chassis=14,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x5 \
    -device id=pci.15,driver=pcie-root-port,port=30,chassis=15,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3.0x6 \
    -device id=pci.16,driver=pcie-pci-bridge,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0 \
    -device id=usb,driver=qemu-xhci,p2=15,p3=15,bus=pci.2,addr=0x0 \
    -device id=scsi0,driver=lsi,bus=pci.16,addr=0x1 \
    -device id=virtio-serial0,driver=virtio-serial-pci,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0 \
    -device id=sata0-0-0,driver=ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=libvirt-2-format,bootindex=2 \
    -device id=sata0-0-1,driver=ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=libvirt-1-format,bootindex=1 \
    -netdev id=hostnet0,type=user \
    -device id=net0,driver=e1000e,netdev=hostnet0,mac=52:54:00:bf:ec:a4,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0 \
    -chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
    -device id=serial0,driver=isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,index=0 \
    -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent \
    -device id=channel0,driver=virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
    -tpmdev passthrough,id=tpm0,cancel-path=/dev/null \
    -device tpm-tis,tpmdev=tpm0 \
    -device id=input0,driver=usb-tablet,bus=usb.0,port=1 \
    -device id=video0,driver=qxl-vga,max_outputs=1,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1 \
    -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
    -device id=redir0,driver=usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 \
    -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \
    -device id=redir1,driver=usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 \
    -device id=balloon0,driver=virtio-balloon-pci,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0 \
    -accel kvm \
    -cpu host,migratable=on,hv-time=on,hv-relaxed=on,hv-vapic=on,hv-spinlocks=0x1fff \
    -m size=8388608k \
    -object id=pc.ram,qom-type=memory-backend-ram,size=8589934592 \
    -overcommit mem-lock=off \
    -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 \
    -uuid 42ee3d0e-2ccd-4427-9bc4-565b277c30b9 \
    -no-user-config \
    -nodefaults \
    -rtc base=localtime,driftfix=slew \
    -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay \
    -global driver=cfi.pflash01,property=secure,value=on \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
    -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 \
    -global ICH9-LPC.noreboot=off \
    -boot strict=on \
    -watchdog-action reset \
    -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \
    -msg timestamp=on \
    -no-shutdown \
    -display sdl

